# Blocking tags firing on certain pages in tag manager

Tags: tags, google-tag-manager, blocking

I have a remarketing code that I do not want to be fired on the homepage but needs to fire on rest of the site. I just want to know the basic setups on the trigger to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Fist go to variables and add the 'Page URL' build-in variable.
After that create a trigger for 'All Pages' with this configuration:

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Can you do this from within the web application itself, rather than in GTM?